# PowerBi Dax to Average the last entries by date in each category

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have the following data and I need to display the Average Value of items using only the most recent input for each item and grouped by sortOrder.

| Date | ItemID | SortOrder | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2020 | 403 | 5 | 1.77 |
| 8/1/2020 | 403 | 1 | 1.77 |
| 8/1/2020 | 429 | 2 | 6.1 |
| 8/1/2020 | 429 | 3 | 11.03 |
| 7/1/2020 | 220 | 4 | 34.23 |
| 7/1/2020 | 403 | 1 | 1.60 |
| 7/1/2020 | 415 | 4 | 7.87 |
| 7/1/2020 | 429 | 2 | 4.97 |
| 7/1/2020 | 429 | 3 | 33.03 |
| 7/1/2020 | 123 | 2 | 18.17 |
| 7/1/2020 | 123 | 3 | 27 |
| 7/1/2020 | 123 | 4 | 50.03 |

Expected Results:    I am able to get the count of items with Count ItemID (Distinct)

| Sort Order | Average of Value | Number Of Items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.77 | 1 |
| 2 | 12.135 | 2 |
| 3 | 19.015 | 2 |
| 4 | 30.71 | 3 |
| 5 | 1.77 | 1 |

Sort order 3 is the problem,  I need to first group it to only 3 entries

1. 8/1/2020    429 3   11.03
2. 7/1/2020    429 3   33.03
3. 7/1/2020    123 3   27

Then remove any duplicate Items,  keeping the newest

1. 8/1/2020    429 3   11.03
2. 7/1/2020    123 3   27

Then display Average for 3 = 19.015

I can create a measure that will return the latest value for each sort order and Project,  but then I cant figure out how to use that measure in an average function

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

[image]

```
Average of Value = 
VAR t =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[ItemID] ), 
    "@val",
    VAR d = CALCULATE( MAX('Table'[Date]))
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Value]), 'Table'[Date] = d)
)

RETURN
AVERAGEX(t, [@val])
```

Comment: Thank You David !!!    I need to take some time and understand this,  but it works!